# how to open web application in a browser without navigation buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, browser

I have a web application, and I want to disable the Back button.
I read and found that I can open the browser without the navigation controls with the function window.open(...).

This is the code:

```
window.open (mywebappURL,"mywindow","status=1,toolbar=0");
```

I tried to put it in my Main.Master page, but I get an infinite loop and the new window is opened as a popup window of my application.

Does anyone knows where should I put this code to get my web application opened in a browser without navigation buttons?

Thanks,
Inbal.

Comment: Best advice out there on this topic is don't do it...

Comment: Web applications should stop trying to be anything other than **web** applications. Embrace the conventions of the www, including the back button.

Comment: I agree with @IrishChieftain. Don't do it. You can still use keyboard  shortcuts to go back. I recommend to use the web as it is intended.

Comment: I agree it is not the best thing to do, but it is a temporary solution for ajax problems. The back button will be back soon :) Another option I have is to change tje click event of the next/prev buttons. Anyone knows how can I do this?

Comment: Use the browser as it was intended to be used.

Answer (score 1):

try this on the link's onclick() event

```
function openPopup(){

  var pathname = (window.location.pathname);
  window.open(pathname+'somePopup.html','','width=800,height=450,resizable=yes,dependent,screenx=80,screeny=80,left=80,top=20,scrollbars=no'); 
  return false;
}
```

and in the html

```
<a href=# onclick="openPopup();">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, make sure the window you're opening is a different URL than the window that's initially visited. So your visitor might arrive at `www.example.com/index.html` which then opens `www.example.com/popup.html`

If you open `index.html` again, the new copy will immediately open a popup, which will immediately open a popup, and there's your infinite loop.

However, as several people have commented already, this is generally discouraged. Among other disadvantages to this approach, popup blockers will likely interpret this as trying to launch a popup advertisement, forcing your visitors to recognize what's happened and change their settings.